# What is the proper model to reduce logic in this situation?

Tags: python, sql, django, schema

I am setting up a model where two players are involved in a competition. I'm leaning towards this model:

```
def match(models.Model):
    player = ForeignKey(Player)
    opponent = ForeignKey(Player)
    score = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    games_won = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    games_lost = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    won_match = BooleanField()
```

There are statistics involved, however, and it would require another pull to find the matching record for the opponent if I want to describe the match in full.

Alternatively I could set up the model to include full stats:

```
def match(models.Model):
    home_player = ForeignKey(Player)
    away_player = ForeignKey(Player)
    home_player_score = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    away_player_score = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    ...
```

But that seems equally bad, as I would have to do two logic sets for one player (to find his scores when he's **home_player** and his scores when he's **away_player**).

The final option is to do two inserts per match, both with full stats, and keep redundant data in the table.

There seems like a better way, and therefore I poll **SO**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id go with the first model and use `select_related()` to avoid the extra db calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to reduce redundancy and maintain consistiency of logic...

Match: 
- id
- name

Match_Player: (2 records per match)
- match_id
- player_id
- is_home

Match_Player_Score:
- match_id
- player_id
- score

Comment: A typical way of reaching a model you're happy with is to normalise everything as far as you can.  Code your logic, then once complete optimise/denomralise where necessary (be it for exec time, space used, maintainability, whatever), but only do so once you have everything else figured.

Comment: So, yes it is highly likely that the last two tables could be combined.  But while you're still evolving a design, separate tables gives more flexibility for the unexpected (or the client's new requirements)

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid having redundant data in the database.  This leaves open the possibility of the database data getting internally inconsistent and messing up everything.

Use a single entry per match, as in your second example.  If you plan ahead, you can accomplish the two sets of logic pretty easily.  Take a look at [proxy models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).  There might be an elegant way to do this -- have all of your logic refer to the data fields through accessors like `get_my_score` and `get_opponent_score`.  Then build a Proxy Model class which swaps home and away.

```
class match(models.Model):

    def get_my_score(self):
        return self.home_player_score

    def get_opponent_score(self):
        return self.away_player_score

    def did_i_win(self):
        return self.get_my_score() > self.get_opponent_score()


class home_player_match(match):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def get_my_score(self):
        return self.away_player_score

    def get_opponent_score(self):
        return self.home_player_score
```

Or maybe you want two Proxy models, and have the names in the base model class be neutral.  The problem with this approach is that I don't know how to convert a class from one proxy model to another without reloading from the database.  You want a "rebless" as in perl.  You could do this by using containment rather than inheritance.  Or maybe just a flag in the wrapper class (not stored in the database) saying whether or not to swap fields.  But I'd recommend some solution like that -- solve the tricky stuff in code and don't let the database get inconsistent.